# Same key in the ViewBag and ViewData in mvc only last one work as both

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I use `ViewBag` and `ViewData` with the same key only the last one works.

I am using this code:

My action part

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Name = "View Bag";
    ViewData["Name"] = "View Data";
    TempData["Name"] = "Temp Data";

    return View();
}
```

My view Part

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">@ViewBag.Name</p>
    <p class="lead">@TempData["Name"]</p>
    <p class="lead">@ViewData["Name"]</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

and My result show on UI

[image]

Comment: `ViewBag` is added as `ViewData` (it just uses `dynamic`). What is your question?

Comment: My question is that ViewBag and ViewData using same key but result same as last one. Why are the same result?

Comment: Because `ViewBag` values are added to the `ViewDataDictionary`, but its a `Dictionary` which must have unique keys, so the second one overwrites the first (if you swapped them, then it would display `"View Bag"` twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ViewBag is a dynamic type. The internal implementation of ViewBag stores Name into ViewData["Name"] (type of ViewDataDictionary), so those 2 are interchangeable. ViewData["Name"] and ViewBag.Name.

Comment: I have implement of your concept is work properly  I have declare only ViewBag.Name and use both ViewBag.Name and ViewData["Name"] on UI both worked